# Is There any difference between rowcount and trancount

Tags: sql-server

SQL SERVER 2012- difference between **@@rowcount and @@trancount**.
Is there any difference between rowcount and trancount in sql server 2012.

Comment: Yes, they are completely different. What makes you think they are not?

Comment: Completely different counts.

Comment: @HoneyBadger: Please help me. i am not getting in what ideal case they are getting used. Thanks

Comment: [rowcount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql) and [trancount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trancount-transact-sql) count very different, unrelated things. So if you want to now the number of rows affected by last statement, use @@rowcount. If, on the other hand you want to count transactions, use @@trancount. It's not that difficult to choose which one you need.

Comment: What did you see in the documentation that wasn't clear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**@@RowCount** returns the Number of Rows affected by the statement last executed

Where **@@trancount** returns the number of Open Transactions in the Current Session

Suppose I have a Table TableA with 5 Rows

```
SELECT * FROM TableA

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

Executing the Above I will get 2 Result sets, The first one will list all the 5 Rows of the TableA and Second will return the Number of Rows affected by the Query ie; 5

But If I run

```
SELECT * FROM TableA

SELECT @@TRANCOUNT
```

This will Return me the Number 0 for the 2nd result set as There are no Open Transactions (Begin Transaction)

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT * FROM TableA

SELECT @@TRANCOUNT

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

And This case will return 1 in the 2nd Result set as there is 1 Open Transaction in the Session